# Prevent User to Select Combo Box correctly in Macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I tried to create userform in Macro and create combo box selection for color. 
[image: Source]

[image: interface]

I have successfully created the combo box as follow and prevent the user to continue without filling the combo box. here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A1:A" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
--------------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select Color!"
    Exit Sub

Else
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = ComboBox1.Value
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
```

However, the user can type random text on the combo box and I can't prevent it. 
Is there any way to make the user can only select the value from provided source? here is the case.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Combo style to fmStyleDropDownList